# Detect spaces in names and multiple mentions

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, meteor

I made a small mention script in javascript, that searches the database for the mentioned user (after @).

```
content = content.replace(/@(\w+)?/g, function(match, contents, offset, content) {
    if(Meteor.users.find({username: contents}).count() > 0) {
        return "<a href=''>@"+Meteor.users.findOne({username: contents}).username+"</a>";
    } else {
        return contents;
    }
});
```

There are two problems here:

1. It doesn't work if a name contains spaces (`@admin` works but `@this is a user` does not)
2. It's very inefficient as meteor has to search the database for every possible result.

Could it be possible to remove all spaces from the mention and still successfully search for the user? If so, how?
Like...
`@MyUsername` but the real username is `My Username`

Comment: well your reg exp is not a global match

Comment: You mean the mention name has a space in it????

Comment: updated the post with some clearer info on point 2

Comment: Is there other things in the string besides the mentions? If yes, how is a regular expression supposed to know the difference between a multiple username and a word?

Comment: yes, it contains an entire set of text, what it should do is simply just to convert `@mentions` to links to the user's profile.

Comment: Append a g to make the regex global (searching all appereances): /@(\w+)( \w+)?( \w+)?/g

Comment: But how is it supposed to know "@Foo Bar is a person"  is a match. Look what stackoverflow does, whitespace is camel case with user names.

Comment: @epascarello is right, even though you are testing in the function, if meteor finds the user, it will become extremely inefficient because it will test all possible permutations of text.

Comment: I believe you are right. I updated the post again, also thanks for the input about adding a `g` to the regex

Comment: At this point it is not a problem with the regex any more, but with the idea. You want to test a large chunk of text for possible user names, all of which can include spaces. No matter how you implement it, assume you would have a @ at the beginning of this comment, you would have to make a meteor test for each symbol of this comment, e.g. A, At, At t, At th, ..., At this poi... and so on.

Comment: I do realise that, which is why I believe it's a better idea to remove all spaces from the mention string. I will most likely start a new question for that.